# nuxt3 project, local images are valid in the development environment but not in the production environment

Tags: nuxt3

I encountered such a problem when writing the nuxt3 project https://www.imageenhan.com/image-cartoon When I use local images in the development environment, they can be displayed normally, but when I use the local images in the development environment, the images in the generation environment But it was lost, this is what I wrote

```
  <div class="blurImg" :style="{ width: blurImgWidth + 'px' }">
      <NuxtImg :src="props.blur_img" alt="image enhancement" loading="lazy" title="image enhancement" />
      <div class="before">{{ $t('Before') }}</div>
   </div>
```

```
let props = defineProps({
blur_img: {
    type: String,
    default: '/_nuxt/assets/img/home/6-modified.webp'
  },
}）
```

How should I write the URL of the image so that the image can be effective in the generation environment?